# .htaccess in public_html returns 404 page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a newbie to .htaccess related stuff, though I'm not to linux nor php development. I'm having an error that's driving crazy.

I have apache with rewrite and userdir modules both enabled. My mod_userdir.conf looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
   UserDir disabled root
   <Directory /home/*/public_html>
      AllowOverride All
      Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
      <Limit GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
         Require all granted
      </Limit>
      <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
         Require all denied
      </LimitExcept>
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I am building a webpage in $HOME/public_html/mywebsite where I have an .htaccess with the code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^images/ - [L]
#RewriteRule ^css/ - [L]
#RewriteRule ^js/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico - [L]
RewriteRule ^(images|css|js|classes)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^PayPal classes/paypal/initPP.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^PDF MakePDF.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([-_0-9a-zA-Z:/]*)$ index.php?PageCall=$1 [L,QSA]

# 400 - Bad request
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?error=400
# 401 - Authorization Required
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php?error=401
# 403 - Forbidden
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?error=403
# 404 - Wrong page
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
# 500 - Internal Server Error
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?error=500
```

My problem is that every accesss to http://localhost/~user/mywebsite returns a 404 page. I guessed is a rewrite problem because, when a comment

```
RewriteRule ^([-_0-9a-zA-Z:/]*)$ index.php?PageCall=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The page shows with php errors related to $_GET variables.

What am I doing wrong?.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I answer myself. Seems AllowOverride On must be written in httpd.conf too. So I looked for

```
# forbid access to the entire filesystem by default
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

And changed AllowOverride to "All".

Comment: Is `$HOME/public_html/mywebsite` same as `/~user/mywebsite`?

Comment: Yes. Absolut path to mywebsite is /home/user/public_html/mywebsite and other web pages without .htaccess are linked to http://localhost/dhouard/someothepage

Answer (score 0):

as your are working in sub directory you have to mention RewriteBase as

```
RewriteBase /home/yourusername/public_html/mywebsite
```

add this line next ot  RewriteEngine On line.